# Grub menu not waiting despite of GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

Tags: boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed along side of windows 7.

The grub menu doesn't seem obey `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`, I see the grub menu there for a split second and it immediately defaults to the first option.

Grub menu worked fine when I first installed ubuntu. I am not able to pinpoint what exactly broke it(maybe some update?). I did resize my ubuntu partition using gparted but am not sure if that is what caused it. here are my settings from etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

How do I fix this?

**Edit:** As suggested by 'kamil' **this is what I have tried so far with no luck** -

1) hold the shift key while booting

2)

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
edit GRUB_TIMEOUT to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`
sudo update-grub
```

3)

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
edit GRUB_TIMEOUT to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`
sudo update-grub2
```

4)

at the end of your /etc/grub.d/00_header file, comment out the if condition except for the regular set timeout line like this:

```
#if [ \${recordfail} = 1 ]; then
# set timeout=-1
#else
set timeout=${GRUB_TIMEOUT}
#fi
```

then `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-grub2`

5) 
install boot repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

**boot-repair output -**

> Boot successfully repaired.
>
> ...
>
> The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS] are far from
>   the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may
>   want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of
>   the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then
>   select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of
>   [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1220468/ - here is the full boot-repair data

Could grub files not being at the start of the disk create such issues?

Comment: I believe the part of the boot config you're pointing to does something like "if the last boot failed, wait indefinitely, else wait 10 sec." -1 usually means "indefinitely". So I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Please post the contents of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this very issue by deleting the file `/boot/grub/grubenv` (which contained the line

`set recordfail=1`  ) and reissuing

`sudo update-grub`

afterwards.

Comment: did not work, did not work even after upgrade to 12.10 ... going to  re-install from scratch some day...

Answer (score 1):

install boot repair

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

boot-repair`

Comment: did not work :( however it said `The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)`. Could grub not being at the start of the disk cause this? http://paste.ubuntu.com/1220468/ - here is repair data

Comment: yes that make sense. try to create a new boot parition

Comment: @kamil - please do not keep adding answers.  Edit your existing answer with more or different information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you almost never want (or need) to edit any files in /etc/grub.d/, as doing so is likely to cause problems (at the very least debconf prompts) when you upgrade Ubuntu. Therefore I highly recommend that you revert any changes you have made in this directory. Creating a separate /boot/ partition won't help either (there's no evidence that you have a BIOS which can't properly handle large drives).

Ubuntu hides the grub menu by default unless it detects another OS, overriding the GRUB_TIMEOUT in /etc/default/grub, that's why you're not seeing a grub menu by default. This is Ubuntu specific, upstream grub does not do this.

The fact that you're *also* not seeing the grub menu when you hold shift suggests that grub isn't getting keypresses at all, and so even if the grub menu were shown you wouldn't be able to interact with it. If that's the case, there are ways that we can try to fix it, just don't be surprised if that happens.

To get grub to show the menu for 10 seconds (overriding Ubuntu's hiding of the menu, and any timeout settings in /etc/default/grub) create a file `/boot/grub/custom.cfg` with the contents `timeout=10`. This solution is safe, simple, easy to revert (delete the file) and should not cause any problems on upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the first section in `/etc/default/grub` file with this one

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then execute `sudo update-grub` in the terminal. Restart your PC and see what happen and let us know this by commenting below the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to `/etc/default/grub` fixes the problem:

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=10
```

Remember to run `sudo update-grub` after that...